# Remove strings and special characters from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove strings and special characters from multiple columns (which contain `nan` values). I only want the numbers to be present. Below is one of my columns. Any help will be appreciated!

```
    OTHER
    0   $300.00
    1   $850.00
    2   $550.00
    3   nan
    4   $1,250.00
    5   $81.00
```

Expected outcome:

```
    OTHER
    0   300.00
    1   850.00
    2   550.00
    3   
    4   1250.00
    5   81.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by filling `NaN` values by empty string, then extract the values by `regex`, then fill the `NaN` values, then finally replace comma by empty string.

```py
>>> (df['OTHER'].fillna('')
    .astype(str)
    .str.extract('(\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False)
    .fillna('')
    .str.replace(',',  ''))

0     300.00
1     850.00
2     550.00
3           
4    1250.00
5      81.00
Name: OTHER, dtype: object
```

But for above data, following should also work fine, i.e. taking the only values that are digit or decimal point `.`:

```py
>>>(df['OTHER']
    .fillna('')
    .astype(str)
    .apply(lambda x: ''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit() or i=='.')))

0     300.00
1     850.00
2     550.00
3           
4    1250.00
5      81.00
Name: OTHER, dtype: object
```

For doing the same thing  on multiple columns, try this:

```py
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col]....#rest of the code from any of above two method
```

Comment: The second method does not apply the changes in the actual dataframe. Maybe there is a `inplace = True` parameter to be specifies?

Comment: Above is for printing purpose, you need to assign it back to the column. Assign it to `df['OTHER']`

Comment: Yup silly of me! It worked Thanks! But if I have multiple columns (say 20) then it would become tedious to perform this for each and every column. Any solution to this?

Comment: Just run a single loop for each column, then assign it to the column

Comment: See the updated answer for multiple columns.

Comment: No. What I mean is out of 30 columns in my dataframe, 20 of them need removing of strings and special characters. The other 10 are categorical and do not need this treatment. Your method for multiple columns applies the treatment to all columns

Comment: Then just replace `for col in df` by `for col in listOfColumns`

Comment: I did it in a different fashion. First I used `iloc` function to get dataframe with required columns. Then I performed the above steps to remove strings and special char. Then I finally concatenated both the dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

to remove nan you can use this instruction

```
df.fillna(0)
```

to remove caracters $ you can use this :

```
df[other] = df[other].replace({'$':''},regex=True)
print (df)
```